# A loop in assembly doesn't work why?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

i have problem. I tried build a loop in assembly (nasm,linux). The loop should "cout" number 0 - 10, but it not work and i don't know why. Here is a code :

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
     xor esi,esi
_ccout:
     cmp esi,10
     jnl _end
     inc esi
     mov eax,4
     mov ebx,1
     mov ecx,esi
     mov edx,2
     int 80h

     jmp _ccout
     _end:
     mov eax,1
     int 80h

section .data
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Does the program segfault? does it never reach the end? Does it output numbers other than 0-10?

Comment: There isn't output, the screen is empty and i don't know why...

Comment: The value you put in `ecx` needs to be the address of a sequence of characters to print. What you're putting in `ecx` is just an integer in the range 0-9.

Comment: Could you tell my what exactly should i modify in this program to start work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the loop is working, but you aren't using the syscall correctly. There are some magic numbers involved here, so let's get that out of the way first:

- 4 is the syscall number for `write`
- 1 is the file descriptor for the standard output

So far, so good. `write` requires a file descriptor, **the address of a buffer** and the length of that buffer or the part of it that it's supposed to write to the file descriptor. So, the way this is supposed to look is similar to

```
mov eax,4                   ; write syscall
mov ebx,1                   ; stdout
mov ecx,somewhere_in_memory ; buffer
mov edx,1                   ; one byte at a time
```

compare that to your code:

```
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,esi  ; <-- particularly here
mov edx,2
int 80h
```

What you are doing there (apart from passing the wrong length) is passing the contents of `esi` to `write` as a memory address from which to read the stuff it's supposed to write to stdout. By pure happenstance this doesn't crash, but there's no useful data at that position  in memory.

In order to solve this, you will need a location in memory to put it. Moreover, since `write` works on characters, not numbers, you'll have to to the formatting yourself by adding '0' (which is 48 in ASCII). All in all, it could look something like this:

```
section .data
     text db 0          ; text is a byte in memory

section .text
global _start

_start:
     xor esi,esi

_ccout:
     cmp esi,10
     jnl _end
     inc esi

     lea eax,['0'+esi]  ; print '0' + esi. lea == load effective address
     mov [text],al      ; is useful here even though we're not really working on addresses

     mov eax,4          ; write
     mov ebx,1          ; to fd 1 (stdout)
     mov ecx,text       ; from address text
     mov edx,1          ; 1 byte
     int 80h

     jmp _ccout

_end:
     mov [text],byte 10 ; 10 == newline

     mov eax,4          ; write that
     mov ebx,1          ; like before.
     mov ecx,text
     mov edx,1
     int 80h

     mov eax,1        
     mov ebx,0
     int 80h
```

The output `123456789:` is probably not exactly what you want, but you should be able to take it from here. Exercise for the reader and all that.

Comment: Could you help mi with program below?? Thanks :D